# Nifi Migration Required for blank Sensitive Properties Key

Tags: java, apache-nifi

*I'm* using nifi 1.14.0 in container where I'm experiencing this problem when I restart nifi.

> Migration Required for blank Sensitive Properties Key

```
erro
2021-09-07 01:15:03,672 INFO [main] o.a.n.p.AbstractBootstrapPropertiesLoader Determined default application properties path to be '/opt/nifi/nifi-current/./conf/nifi.properties'

2021-09-07 01:15:03,684 INFO [main] o.a.nifi.properties.NiFiPropertiesLoader Loaded 202 properties from /opt/nifi/nifi-current/./conf/nifi.properties

2021-09-07 01:15:03,700 ERROR [main] o.a.nifi.properties.NiFiPropertiesLoader Flow Configuration [./conf/flow.xml.gz] Found: Migration Required for blank Sensitive Properties Key [nifi.sensitive.props.key]

2021-09-07 01:15:03,704 ERROR [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Failure to launch NiFi due to java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There was an issue decrypting protected properties

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There was an issue decrypting protected properties

at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.initializeProperties(NiFi.java:346)

at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.convertArgumentsToValidatedNiFiProperties(NiFi.java:314)

at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.convertArgumentsToValidatedNiFiProperties(NiFi.java:310)

at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:302)

Caused by: org.apache.nifi.properties.SensitivePropertyProtectionException: Sensitive Properties Key [nifi.sensitive.props.key] not found: See Admin Guide section [Updating the Sensitive Properties Key]


at org.apache.nifi.properties.NiFiPropertiesLoader.getDefaultProperties(NiFiPropertiesLoader.java:226)

at org.apache.nifi.properties.NiFiPropertiesLoader.get(NiFiPropertiesLoader.java:209)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.initializeProperties(NiFi.java:341)
```

and in my file nifi.properties

```
security properties 
nifi.sensitive.props.key=l5bGW7Miy5Vv5sGTr8tXqLyVfpOdTnY0
nifi.sensitive.props.key.protected=l5bGW7Miy5Vv5sGTr8tXqLyVfpOdTnY0
nifi.sensitive.props.algorithm=NIFI_PBKDF2_AES_GCM_256
nifi.sensitive.props.provider=BC
nifi.sensitive.props.additional.keys=
```

can someone help me?

Comment: According to official [docs](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#nifi_sensitive_props_key), in 1.14 or later version, it generates a random value when `nifi.sensitive.props.key` is empty. So I "guess" you upgraded from 1.13 to 1.14 but didn't remove the old docker volume, which may cause the newer nifi.properties is replaced by the old one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all I found so far is this nifi issue [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-8230).

If you find a nice workaround or simple solution please let me know :)

Greetings Oliver

EDIT:

Just found [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-8943) Issue. I applied the changes in my own start.sh and it worked.

```
if [ -n "${NIFI_SENSITIVE_PROPS_KEY}" ]; then
    prop_replace 'nifi.sensitive.props.key' "${NIFI_SENSITIVE_PROPS_KEY}"
fi
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.